# Export Blender model to Unity missing texture

Tags: unity-game-engine, model, 3d, blender

I created model from blender 3.6 had use material from blenderkit and when i try to export and import to unity. Texture and material are missing. Somebody help me, thanks.

i had extract some image from shading in blender and copy to folder textures in unity but not resovled my problem!

My blender file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zDRt46gs_z5Vmi7FdiTeFnBZyfYAS0eA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide more information about your task and problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recreate the material in Unity. Just import the textures and the model into Unity, then right-click in the file browser and select "New Material". Select this material in the inspector.

The default shader should be fine, but if it's not just select the standard lit shader.

From here you can assign each texture type (Albedo/base, Roughness, normal, etc.) to their respective fields.

With this material created, you now need to drag your model into the scene view so it is added as a GameObject. You can now drag the material you created onto it. After this, save the object as a prefab so you can use it throughout your game.